# Performance consideration - using Server controls ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html

I just wanted to know if there is any performance variation when we use

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

instead of

```
<input type=text />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely, `<asp:TextBox runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>` is a server side code and it invokes the server process with state management etc. It will take part in init till render and all server process. Keep it in mind that anything that is rendered onto a browser is pure HTML and the server side control will have to be rendered to equivallent HTML before it is shown.

So what I have said is the difference. But, the performance variation, the degree will be very low. But still if you do not need any special server side coding associated with the text box, it is advisable that you use the humble HTML only.